# shell 'SED' - use variabels

Tags: linux, shell

I´m looking for a way to remove the entry in `/etc/passwd`.

So I did this

```
sed -i /$user/d /etc/passwd
```

but looks like I can´t use variabels in sed. I tryed this too:

```
sed -i "/"$user"/d /etc/passwd"
```

but did not work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unless `$user` contains problematic characters, simply `sed "/$user/d" /etc/passwd`. Btw, you need to be careful with the `-i` option unless you are sure that the command works since it changes the original file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do like:

```
sed -i.bak "/$user/d" /etc/passwd
```

create back up before you do inplace operation.

```
Output:
132$ echo $user
foo
133$ cat test.txt
ajdjfd
lmass/d
lmass/d
foo
dff
134$ sed -i "/$user/d" test.txt
135$ cat test.txt
ajdjfd
lmass/d
lmass/d
dff
136$
```

Answer (score 0):

**sed -i '/login/s/foo/bar/g' /path/to/the/file**

This command replace foo with bar whichever line contains word 'login'.
-i will save the changes in the file